# How will I prove that determinant $det: GL (R) → R$ is a homomorphism? where R is a ring and $G=GL(R)_{n}$ a group

Tags: lie-groups

My Algebra teacher made that statement and asked why it was true. I am not able to formulate a correct demonstration. I thought of something using Det (AB) = Det (A). Det (B) but I think I'm wrong.

Comment: What exactly does "$\Bbb R$" mean? You need to be a bit more specific if this problem is to make enough sense to be answerable.

Comment: Sorry, I edited

Comment: That's still not entirely enough. $\Bbb R$ is a set. Presumably you want a group. Which group exactly is it that you want? Being clear about these things is a good first step to an answer, whether you want to find it yourself or want someone else to help you.

Comment: Right, I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you’re absolutely right!

The formula $$\det AB = \det A \det B$$ is exactly saying that $\det$ is an homomorphism between the groups $(GL_n(\mathbb R), \times)$ and $(\mathbb R^*, \cdot)$.

Comment: I thought it was very simple, however, according to the definition of homomorphism and the formula I tried to use, things made sense.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for noticing the typos... hopefully fixed.

Comment: I should go to bed...